# Display users First and last name in plain text from the database or give an error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a html page that sends value pass to log.php :

```
<?php 
$PHONE = $_POST['pass'];

mysql_connect('host.com', 'user', 'pass'); mysql_select_db('userdb');  

$results = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM `details` WHERE PASS='$PASS'",
mysql_real_escape_string($PASS))) or die(mysql_error()); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{ $rows[1] = $row; }
echo "Welcome ";
echo "$rows[1][FNAME]." ".$rows[1][LNAME]"
echo " you are logged in successfully"

?>
```

I get the result in log.php file in this form when value 'pass' is not being registered in database:

```
Welcome [//here user's first & last name if registered or remains blank] you are logged in successfully
```

I have table 'details' created

```
FNAME-First name
LNAME-Lastname
BIRTHDAY-Birthday
PHONE- user's no.
PASS- user's password.
```

My Question is , I want to just display ' You are not registered user' when pass value is not been registered in the database.Any help would be greatfull ?

Comment: for authorization you should get record from the database by username and then check the password. `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query)` returns number of rows found

Comment: try to echo your query and paste here let us see what your query is echoing, may be you are providing a wrong field or the $pass value is empty

Comment: What is $PASS? Perhaps you meant $PHONE?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you actually get a record or not using [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php),

```
$results = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM `details` WHERE PASS='$PASS'",
           mysql_real_escape_string($PASS))) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0){
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
   { 
      $rows[1] = $row; 
   }
   echo "Welcome ";
   echo $rows[1]['FNAME']." ".$rows[1]['LNAME'];
   echo "You are logged in successfully";
}
else{
    //Redirect them back with error message
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?err='You are not registered user'");
}
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/a8550571/public_html/Log.php file, its seems somethings going wrong in your code.

Comment: I direct you how you can pass data to other page. You can solve a parse error by yourself , debuging the same. Btw I have update my answer `echo $rows[1]['FNAME']." ".$rows[1]['LNAME'];` you had a syntax error near this lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($rows[1][FNAME])){
    echo 'You are not registered user';
}
else{
    echo "Welcome ";
    echo "$rows[1][FNAME]." ".$rows[1][LNAME]";
    echo " you are logged in successfully";
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/a8550571/public_html/Log.php, this error is shown from your code.

Comment: @user2513330 I forgot the semicolons, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You took value in $phone variable for password and in select query used PASS= $PASS so how can it run?

Change this then run like below:

```
$results = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM `details` WHERE PASS='$PHONE'",
mysql_real_escape_string($PHONE))) or die(mysql_error());
```